# Не могу сделать restore в postgreSQL

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Всплывает вот такая ошибка. В чем проблема?

Comment: проблема в том что `pg_restore` не видит файл `D:\Загрузки\assortment_db.backup`. `dir D:\Загрузки\assortment_db.backup` работает если запустить эту комманду в `cmd.exe`?

Comment: в cmd.exe находит этот файл

Comment: может пользователь под которым работает `pg_restore` не имеет права на чтение  `D:\Загрузки`?

Comment: я попробовал с диска С найти, все получилось, спасибо